# Nested mapping in elasticsearch with using Java API. Как создать запрос?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно реализовать следующую задачу используя elasticsearch и Java API к этой базе:
есть тип "user" с id "womens" и в него мне нужно добавить, к примеру, 2 юзера с данными. Должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
{
    "_index": "company",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "womens",
    "_source": {[
               "Alisa: "{
                "old": "20",
                "married": "no"
                 },
               "Tatiana: "{
                "old": 25,
                "married": "yes"
                 }
              ]}
}
```

В дальнейшем мне нужно будет из типа "users" по id "womens" получать всех юзеров или конкретного из них по какому-то параметру, а так же обновлять и удалять эти данные. Нагуглить решение не смог, поэтому пишу сюда. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Вы не можете искать внутри документа, вы можете либо вытянуть womens, либо нет. И, кстати, women - это уже множественное число.

Comment: можно ли как-то решить описанную задачу?

Comment: нет, пока вы храните данные в одном документе. у вас должны быть разные документы с атрибутами sex: male / female.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. насчет women согласен, просто голова туго соображает под конец дня.